# PHP detecting correct variable type

Tags: php, variables, types

I'm reading the contents of a text file into an array, and need to be sure which type of a specific entry is.

However my code sometimes is detecting empty values as integer and/or decimal. If the same script runs later for the same file,
the type is detected right.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
$file = fopen($file, "r");
$row = 0;

while ($fscv = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) {
    if ($row == 0) {
        $header = $fscv;
    } elseif ($row == 1) {
        $values = $fscv;
    }
        $row++;
}
fclose($file);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    switch (true) {
        case $value == NULL:
            $value = '';
            // do something
            break;
        case $value == '':
            $value = '';
            // do something
            break;
        case $this->validateDate($value):
            // do something
            break;
        case is_int($value):
            // do something
            break;
        case is_numeric($value):
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            // do something
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not use http://php.net/gettype, and use a switch based on the result of that?

Comment: you are switching on `true` why?. shouldnt it be `switch($value){` ?

Comment: all cas are false or true in your switch..

Comment: @Qirel That sounds like terrible advice and whoever upvoted it should be ashamed. `echo gettype('4');` is a string...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So? If you're interested in the ***type***, that is correct.

Comment: @dwing You really need to become familiar with this page: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @deceze OP is not interested in that. All of his inputs come from a text file so EVERYTHING is text, `gettype()` is pointless. OP needs the likes of `ctype_digit()` and whatnot.

Comment: @Monkey *Probably* agreed, but that's rather vaguely implied.

Comment: @dwin265 Please post a sample of the contents of the file and show how you plan to read the data into your switch statement.

Comment: @Akintunde007 - not with `switch` when attempting to match on the *type* of variable... `switch($value) { case '': ... break; }` will match on any *falsey* value; the workaround is to use `switch(true)` but then you need to explicitly match the type with something like `case $value === '':`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus code is updated.

Comment: @deceze this will always return, that my values are a string, which may be correct in a technical way, but is not what I need

Comment: @all: The problem is that I do not need to know the type of the variable, which may be indeed a string. But the type of the content. There may be  three different types: date (which wasn't a problem), int&decimals, everything else including empty (string)

Comment: @dwing265 I posted an answer, let me know your thoughts

Comment: Technically if you *"do not need to know the type of variable"* then you're really just interested in the format of a given string - you may as well just use `preg_match()` then.

Comment: @dwing265 any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation, you are better off using `if(){}elseif(){}else{}` like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen($file, "r");
$row = 0;

while ($fscv = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) {
    if ($row == 0) {
        $header = $fscv;
    } elseif ($row == 1) {
        $values = $fscv;
    }
    $row++;
}
fclose($file);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    if( $value === '' ) {
        // the string is empty
    }
    elseif(ctype_digit($value)) {
        // we have an integer
    }
    elseif(strtolower($value) === 'true') {
        // boolean true?
    }
    elseif(strtolower($value) === 'false') {
        // boolean false?
    }
    elseif(
        substr_count($value, '.') === 1 && // single period
        strpos($value, '.') !== (strlen($value)-1) && // period cannot be the last character
        preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $value) === '.' // remove all digits and make sure that only a period is left
    ) {
        // float?
    }
    elseif($this->validateDate($value)) {
        // date?
    }
    else{
        // idk, do something
    }
}
?>
```